# Is the term "carriage return" outdated in a (near) post-typewriter world?

Tags: word-usage, archaicisms, technology

When we say "Return key" or "Enter key", either are clear in meaning to those with even very light keyboarding experience. But "Return" is a diminutive of "Carriage Return". Fully saying/writing "Carriage Return" may be unfamiliar to the ears of those who work with computers daily yet have never touched a typewriter.

In a computing sense "Carriage Return" (ASCII character 13) DOES mean something very different in comparison to "Line Feed" (ASCII character 10). So, for a certain audience, "Carriage Return" is meaningful. But for a broad audience, should "Carriage Return key" be avoided and "Return key" be the preferred usage?

Comment: What is this "typewriter" thing?

Comment: This is context dependent. Many computer keyboards have an enter key and no return key, but Macs notably have return keys. People who care about keyboards enough to talk about them or read what you write about them may be more familiar with historical keyboards and how they are different from modern keyboards.  You have to know your audience to know what words to use to get across the idea you intend.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that *carriage return* is not understood by anyone? Barring that, this is an entirely subjective question without any clear answer.

Comment: 'return' for the key or action of moving the cursor to the beginning of the next line, 'newline' for the (invisible?) character indicating to do so.

Comment: I cannot recall seeing a single instance of *carriage return key* in a personal computing context in the last two and a half decades, but apparently you do. I would point out then that the fact that the original circumstances surrounding the adoption of a term have changed does not invalidate the continued use of the term. Just with smartphones alone we purchase *lines*, and *dial* and *hang up* our calls, and can send videos by *text* or *cut and paste* them into email we *CC* our buddies on.

Comment: My personal preference: I use `Return` for the key, `Carriage Return` for the character.